# I want to generate this textbox with a model's I.d when i'm creating and also making the textbox uneditable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, code-first, strongly-typed-view

> This is my model

```
    [Key]
    public int ConsultId { get; set; }
```

`

> This is my View
>   `

```
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConsultId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

        @Html.IdFor(m=>m.ConsultId)

        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConsultId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

What I want to do is,i want the textbox for the ConsultId to be autogenerated

Comment: This is a create view though.. but i want to auto-generate the text-box with an i.d.. Is there anyway i can do it using a strongly typed view? Your assistance will be much appreciated

Comment: What about using Guid instead of int type ? 
in the getter of your property check if the value is equal to Guid.Empty then generate new one.

Comment: @CodeNotFound How do i do that?

Comment: You not generating a textbox. To generate a textbox you need `@Html.TextBoxFor()`and if you want it to be readonly, set the htmlAttributes `new { @readonly = "readonly" }`, but if this is a 'Create` view then you should not be including a control for the ID property anyway

Comment: @StephenMuecke i know i shouldnt be putting that in my create view, but i really need to pass the i.d of the consultation i just created to the next page which i have no idea how to go about it

Comment: If you mean that `ConsultId` is not the identity property, then that's fine. Just use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ConsultId, new { @readonly = "readonly" })` or `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Consult.Id)` if you don't really need it to be visible

Comment: Thanks for your reply @StephenMuecke..but (m => m.ConsultId) is the identity property and i really need to get the id of (m => m.ConsultId) from the view and pass it to the next page

Comment: Note also there is no point including `@Html.ValidationMesageFor()`

Comment: Autogenerating the id means you need to create a primary key depends on a table value?

Comment: @AyomideFajobi Something like this `private Guid _ConsultId; public Guid ConsultId { get { if(_ConsultId == Guid.Empty) { _ConsultId = Guid.NewGuid(); } return _ConsultId; } set { _ConsultId = value }`

Comment: @AyomideFajobi, based on your comment that `ConsultId` is the identity, then it should not be in a create view (the model does not exist yet in the database so it does not have an ID). When you POST, get the newly created ID and pass it to the next view.